# Using font character as a map icon in KML

Tags: kml, font-awesome

In the current project a custom equivalent for Font Awesome is used for all required icons in the web application.

Is it possible to use Font Awesome, or some other font based symbol instead of PNG graphics as a KML icon?

Comment: What are you using to display the KML?

Comment: Embedded Google Maps.